# Search values in columns and return 'true' or false' in a new one

Tags: r

I have this data, `header_class`, which contains info on the field's class:

```
> header_class <- data.frame(header = c("name","type","format"),
+                            field = c("C1","C1","C2"))
> header_class
  header field
1   name    C1
2   type    C1
3 format    C2
```

And I have this other `data`, with the rows of the header as columns.

```
> data <- data.frame(name = c("","Name2","Name3"),
+                    type = c(NA,"","Type3"),
+                    format = c("A",NA,"C"))
> data
   name  type format
1        <NA>      A
2 Name2         <NA>
3 Name3 Type3      C
```

I need a function to validate some conditions, like, for example:

If there is `at least one field filled`, it should return a `TRUE` value in a `new column`, like this:

```
> result
   name  type format   C1    C2
1        <NA>      A FALSE TRUE
2 Name2         <NA> TRUE  FALSE
3 Name3 Type3      C TRUE  TRUE
```

I've tried using this, but it won't work with it, because it also has `""` or `"  "` values, for example.

```
> result <- cbind(data, sapply(split(as.character(header_class$header), as.character(header_class$field)),
+                                     function(x) rowSums(!is.na(data[x])) >0))
> result
   name  type format   C1    C2
1        <NA>      A TRUE  TRUE
2 Name2         <NA> TRUE FALSE
3 Name3 Type3      C TRUE  TRUE
```

I've also tried to add the `|` condition to check if `rowSums(data[x]!="")` but still wouldn't do it and returned `TRUE`.

What am I doing wrong? If there's any other suggestions on how to approach it I'd also appreciate. 
I also need to do it on a huge dataset with over 400 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Run this here on your data before your algo:

This will replace any empty cell `"", " ", "  .. "` and so on with NA.

```
data[] <- lapply(data,sub,pattern="^\\s*$",replacement=NA)
```

Comment: it was a nice way of preparing the data before, thank you.

Comment: This is a good practice to clean up data first and then work on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure I understand the issue, or how `header_class` comes into play.

The following reproduces your expected output

```
transform(data,
    C1 = (!is.na(name) & name != "") | (!is.na(type) & type != ""),
    C2 = !is.na(format) & format != "")
#   name  type format    C1    C2
#1        <NA>      A FALSE  TRUE
#2 Name2         <NA>  TRUE FALSE
#3 Name3 Type3      C  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

### Update

For a more general case with multiple column groups `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, ... which are defined in `header_class`, you could do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(k, v, -row) %>%
    left_join(header_class, by = c("k" = "header")) %>%
    group_by(row, field) %>%
    mutate(flag = sum(is.na(v)) + sum(v == "", na.rm = T) < n()) %>%
    spread(k, v) %>%
    spread(field, flag) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(first(.[!is.na(.)])))
## A tibble: 3 x 6
#    row format name  type  C1    C2
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <lgl> <lgl>
#1     1 A      ""    NA    FALSE TRUE
#2     2 NA     Name2 ""    TRUE  FALSE
#3     3 C      Name3 Type3 TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I think `!(is.na(name) & is.na(type))` should be `!(is.na(name) | is.na(type))`. Please double check your answer

Comment: @A.Suliman Perhaps; I am confused what OPs expected output is. I see two different `result`s.

Comment: OP ask for the 1st result. The 2nd result is what OP tried so far

Comment: header_class comes to classify what kind of field the headers belong to. So, if both name and type are from the field C1, if theyre both empty, it shouldn't return true as your code did! and that's what i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @A.Suliman Ok, in that case we need to check for empty strings (as well as `NA`s); I don't think the solution from your comment addresses this, although it coincidentally gives the correct solution.

Comment: @LuccaRamalho Hmm, I've made an edit to reproduce your expected output. You need to check for `NA`s and empty strings `""`.

Comment: and also, i have more than 20 fields with lots of headers, doing it manually would take too much time...

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks a lot, it worked for the data i presented! Is there a way to do another code and run for whenever cases instead of typing one by one?

Comment: *"Is there a way to do another code and run for whenever cases instead of typing one by one?"* I'm sorry but I really struggle to understand what you're trying to do and what the whole point is. This seems like a very odd data structure/operation.

Comment: @LuccaRamalho Ok, I've added an update. Perhaps this is what you're after.

Comment: @LuccaRamalho I'm curious: Did my update work for your more general case?